# When we almost finished / When we were finishing

Tags: past-tense

> When **we almost finished** planting the young trees, father brought 10 rose bushes.
>
> When **we were finishing** planting the young trees, father brought 10 rose bushes.

Which sentence is more idiomatic? I had a surprise that "finish" can be used in the Past Progressive. I see both versions are popular - [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=almost+finished%2Cwere+finishing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). Which one would be common in the mentioned context or both sound good?

Comment: Neither version is grammatically correct or idiomatic for reasons unrelated to your original question - we don't say "to plant" here, we would say *planting*.

Comment: Both are "half right". It's *When we **were almost finished planting** [the] young trees, father brought 10 rose bushes.* But I think it's more "elegant" to switch to *When we **had** almost finished planting the young trees...* Note that your NGram is completely irrelevant - it doesn't tell us anything apart from the obvious fact that most references to "finished/finishing" won't include the word "almost".

Comment: @stangdon, Why? With verb "finish" we can use "to+infinitive" or "verb+ing". From grammar rule (in my grammar book) we can choose either.

Comment: @Sergei  I don't know exactly what your grammar book says, but "I finish *to plant*" is definitely wrong.  *Finish* (unlike *start*) only takes a noun or gerund.

Comment: @stangdon, Yeah, I found that rule. You are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To ***finish*** can certainly be used in Past Progressive form *(I **was finishing** my dinner when the phone range)*. But it's not idiomatic for OP's context, because *[to be] **almost finishing*** doesn't make much sense.

Per my comment under the question, I would use a Past Perfect construction here. The fact that OP's example includes ***almost*** doesn't affect the temporal relationship between things that were *already* happening when Y happened (and we use Past Perfect for the *earlier* action or process). So to my ear the natural form is the *first* of these two...

> 1: *When we **had** almost finished planting the young trees...*
> 2: *When we **were** almost finished planting the young trees...*

I don't even know what to call the verb construction in #2, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20was%20finished%20doing%2CI%20had%20finished%20doing&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) chart shows just how much it's gained traction in recent decades...

[image]

Comment: Your examples are completely different from mines. I compared Past Simple vs Past Continuous. Could you discuss my examples, please?

Comment: I already commented under your question that your NGram is completely irrelevant - it doesn't tell us anything apart from the obvious fact that most references to "finished/finishing" won't include the word "almost". I don't want to be rude, but what else is there to say about that?

Comment: I am comparing the difference between "almost finished" & "were finishing", but you don't want to see it.

Comment: It's a meaningless comparison. Would you compare "were watching" with "almost watched"? And why "almost"? Why not "nearly" or "practically" or "just about finished"?

Comment: Because it was my decision to ask this question. Why do you need to change my questions it's not understandable.

Comment: Where did you see "almost finishing" in my question? And I'm not asking about "the relative frequency". I'm asking about the difference between two sentences. Read again my questions. I edited them yesterday. If the difference between them is nearly zero, it's also a good answer. Notice that I'm a learner, I'm not a writer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142554/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-sergei).